# Pandas error on rename axis error on arguments passed

Tags: pandas

I have a Dataframe that returns count of sales done for a time frame which is stored to a variable `total_sale_count`

```
total_sale_count_old = pd.DataFrame(total_sale_count, columns=['TotalSaleCount'])
total_stop_count = total_sale_count_old.set_index('TotalSaleCount').T.rename_axis('Total Sales').rename_axis(None, 1).reset_index()
```

The above throws an error

```
TypeError: rename_axis() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data `total_sale_count` ?

Comment: Or what is `total_sale_count.info()` ?

Comment: Could you check your pandas version, @dark horse?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need:

```
total_sale_count = pd.Series([1,2,3], index=list('abc'))

total_stop_count = pd.DataFrame([total_sale_count], index=['TotalSaleCount'])
print (total_stop_count)
                a  b  c
TotalSaleCount  1  2  3
```